# Spring Web Flows transition events. Where do they come from?

Tags: xml, spring, spring-webflow

```
 <view-state id="reviewBooking">
        <transition on="confirm" to="bookingConfirmed" />
        <transition on="revise" to="enterBookingDetails" />
        <transition on="cancel" to="bookingCancelled" />
    </view-state>
```

In this XML snippet there are given three different "transition" event types. "confirm", "revise" and "cancel". Does anybody know where to get a full list of possible events and their descriptions? Or are they user defined and I just didn't realized that?

Comment: I'm getting -1 without explaination? Cmon guys at least tell me what I'm doing wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

they are user defined. in your html you can use a submit button:

```
<input type="submit" value="Confirm" name="_eventId_confirm" id="eventId_confirmButton">
```

the key part being the name which will map to the event "confirm" of your flow.

you can also use an anchor:

```
<a href="${flowExecutionUrl}&_eventId=revise">Revise</a>
```

this link will map to the "revise" event of your flow.

You can use submit buttons or links depending on whether or not you need to submit forms.

I suggest you read [Spring Webflow Documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-webflow/docs/current/reference/html/)